# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: .....EventProcessor: method <init>()V not found

Tags: java, spring, scala, aspectj

My goal is to weave some custom aspect on the `handle` method of all my command handlers.

my custom aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
class EventProcessor @Autowired()(private val eventRepository: EventRepository) {

  @Before("execution(* com.mypackage.*.application.commands.*.*(..))")
  def listen() {
    DomainEventPublisher.instance().subscribe(new DomainEventSubscriber[Event] {

      def handleEvent(domainEvent: Event) {
        eventRepository.save(domainEvent)
      }

      def subscribedToEventType = {
        classOf[Event]
      }
    })
  }

}
```

An example of `commandHandler`:

```
trait CommentBlog {

  def handle(command: MyCommand): ValidationNel[Failure, Unit]

}
```

The whole works great when the custom aspect is weaved at Runtime.
For production, I expect it to be weave at compile time, so I use a great [plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-aspectj/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/SbtAspectj.scala) to achieve it.

However, I get a `NoAspectBoundException` caused by this error when running:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: .....EventProcessor: method <init>()V not found
```

What is this method init exactly? What may be the root cause ?

Comment: No idea concerning AOP, but it looks like the plugin simply can't find the default constructor of `EventProcessor`.

Comment: However the plugin succeeded to weave `@Transactional` aspect on my classes at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found the stuff :)

As @Landei raised up, default constructor was not found because it was not defined! 
In Scala:

`class EventProcessor @Autowired()(private val eventRepository: EventRepository) {` creates a one-arg constructor accepting an `EventRepository`.

So my solution is:

```
@Aspect
class EventProcessor  {

  @Before("execution(* com.mypackage.*.application.commands.*.*(..))")
  def listen() {
    DomainEventPublisher.instance().subscribe(new DomainEventSubscriber[Event] {

      def handleEvent(domainEvent: Event) {
        val eventRepository = SpringContext.ctx.getBean("eventRepository", classOf[EventRepository])
        eventRepository.save(domainEvent)
      }

      def subscribedToEventType = {
        classOf[Event]
      }
    })
  }

}
```